Smoke/Fire Simulation simulates Gaps between Frames


Hi, i want to simulate fire/smoke and it doesn't has a smooth transition, i tried increasing Sampling Supsteps, but since the Emitter or the Domain isn't moving it didn't change anyting.
I don't know how to resolve this issue please help or give tips.
Thank you very much

You're "shooting" it out at 100 m/s, which means if you've set your scene to let's say 25 FPS, the fire/smoke moved 4 m between two frames. The Sanpling Substeps are set to 1, which means there are not sufficient steps inbetween to calculate the simulation. I would set it much higher at these speeds. How much depends on what looks good enough to you and still has acceptable baking times.

Thanks for the comment, yes I had the same idea so I increased the Sampling Sups to 40 which made no difference. But maybe I will try it again and put the framerste to something like 120 FPS and later increase the play rate in Unreal Engine. Thanks for the Idea

Or are the flames going through or past some effector objects with which they collide? I cannot see that. If so, this might create some kind of shockwave effect... and of course the effectors should have enough substeps, too. And in the domain under Use Adaptive Time Steps perhaps increase the Timesteps Minimum from 1 to 2, or even 3 but this increases the bake time quite a bit.
